# Regex for bible references

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on some code for an online bible. I need to identify when references are written out. I have looked all through stackoverflow and tried various regex examples but they all seem to fail with single books (eg Jude) as they require a number to proceed the book name. Here is my solution so far :

```
/((?:(I+|1st|2nd|3rd|First|Second|Third|1|2|3))?( )?(Gen|Ge|Gn|Exo|Ex|Exod|Lev|Le|Lv|Num|Nu|Nm|Nb|Deut|Dt|Josh|Jos|Jsh|Judg|Jdg|Jg|Jdgs|Rth|Ru|Sam|Samuel|Kings|Kgs|Kin|Chron|Chronicles|Ezra|Ezr|Neh|Ne|Esth|Es|Job|Job|Jb|Pslm|Ps|Psalms|Psa|Psm|Pss|Prov|Pr|Prv|Eccles|Ec|Song|So|Canticles|Song of Songs|SOS|Isa|Is|Jer|Je|Jr|Lam|La|Ezek|Eze|Ezk|Dan|Da|Dn|Hos|Ho|Joel|Joe|Jl|Amos|Am|Obad|Ob|Jnh|Jon|Micah|Mic|Nah|Na|Hab|Zeph|Zep|Zp|Haggai|Hag|Hg|Zech|Zec|Zc|Mal|Mal|Ml|Matt|Mt|Mrk|Mk|Mr|Luk|Lk|John|Jn|Jhn|Acts|Ac|Rom|Ro|Rm|Co|Cor|Corinthians|Gal|Ga|Ephes|Eph|Phil|Php|Col|Col|Th|Thes|Thess|Thessalonians|Ti|Tim|Timothy|Titus|Tit|Philem|Phm|Hebrews|Heb|James|Jas|Jm|Pe|Pet|Pt|Peter|Jn|Jo|Joh|Jhn|John|Jude|Jud|Rev|The Revelation|Genesis|Exodus|Leviticus|Numbers|Deuteronomy|Joshua|Judges|Ruth|Samuel|Kings|Chronicles|Ezra|Nehemiah|Esther|Job|Psalms|Psalm|Proverbs|Ecclesiastes|Song of Solomon|Isaiah|Jeremiah|Lamentations|Ezekiel|Daniel|Hosea|Joel|Amos|Obadiah|Jonah|Micah|Nahum|Habakkuk|Zephaniah|Haggai|Zechariah|Malachi|Matthew|Mark|Luke|John|Acts|Romans|Corinthians|Galatians|Ephesians|Philippians|Colossians|Thessalonians|Timothy|Titus|Philemon|Hebrews|James|Peter|John|Jude|Revelation))(([ .)\n|])([^a-zA-Z]))([\d])?([:\d])?([:\d])?/gi;
```

Here is the regex code with some sample text to match:
https://regexr.com/5pfg3

On the above you will notice, Jude if double spaced will work. If I put a full stop after it will work. I know the issue is this section :

```
(([ .)\n|])([^a-zA-Z]))
```

What I want is to match spaces, brackets, new lines BUT not a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not match as it expects 2 characters using `(([ .)\n|])([^a-zA-Z]))` where the second one can not be a char a-zA-Z due to the negated character class, so it can not match the `s` in `Jude some`.

What you might do is make the character class in the second part optional, if you intent to keep all the capture groups.

You could also add word boundaries `\b` to make the pattern a bit more performant as it is right now.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2GoMc4/1)

(**Note** that *Jude* is listed twice in the alternation)

---

If you only want to use 3 groups, you can write the first part as:

```
\b(?:(I+|1st|2nd|3rd|First|Second|Third|[123]) )?
```

The second part will be the alternation with the names, and in the 3rd part you can match one of the character class followed by the digit part and make that optional as a whole (so you don't match a trailing space or char after the word without the digits).

```
(?:[ .)\n|](\d+(?::\d+){0,2}\b))?
```

The full pattern will look like

```
\b(?:(I+|1st|2nd|3rd|First|Second|Third|[123]) )?(Gen|Ge|Gn|Exo|Ex|Exod|Lev|Le|Lv|Num|Nu|Nm|Nb|Deut|Dt|Josh|Jos|Jsh|Judg|Jdg|Jg|Jdgs|Rth|Ru|Sam|Samuel|Kings|Kgs|Kin|Chron|Chronicles|Ezra|Ezr|Neh|Ne|Esth|Es|Job|Job|Jb|Pslm|Ps|Psalms|Psa|Psm|Pss|Prov|Pr|Prv|Eccles|Ec|Song|So|Canticles|Song of Songs|SOS|Isa|Is|Jer|Je|Jr|Lam|La|Ezek|Eze|Ezk|Dan|Da|Dn|Hos|Ho|Joel|Joe|Jl|Amos|Am|Obad|Ob|Jnh|Jon|Micah|Mic|Nah|Na|Hab|Zeph|Zep|Zp|Haggai|Hag|Hg|Zech|Zec|Zc|Mal|Mal|Ml|Matt|Mt|Mrk|Mk|Mr|Luk|Lk|John|Jn|Jhn|Acts|Ac|Rom|Ro|Rm|Co|Cor|Corinthians|Gal|Ga|Ephes|Eph|Phil|Php|Col|Col|Th|Thes|Thess|Thessalonians|Ti|Tim|Timothy|Titus|Tit|Philem|Phm|Hebrews|Heb|James|Jas|Jm|Pe|Pet|Pt|Peter|Jn|Jo|Joh|Jhn|John|Jude|Jud|Rev|The Revelation|Genesis|Exodus|Leviticus|Numbers|Deuteronomy|Joshua|Judges|Ruth|Samuel|Kings|Chronicles|Ezra|Nehemiah|Esther|Job|Psalms|Psalm|Proverbs|Ecclesiastes|Song of Solomon|Isaiah|Jeremiah|Lamentations|Ezekiel|Daniel|Hosea|Joel|Amos|Obadiah|Jonah|Micah|Nahum|Habakkuk|Zephaniah|Haggai|Zechariah|Malachi|Matthew|Mark|Luke|John|Acts|Romans|Corinthians|Galatians|Ephesians|Philippians|Colossians|Thessalonians|Timothy|Titus|Philemon|Hebrews|James|Peter|John|Revelation)\b(?:[ .)\n|](\d+(?::\d+){0,2}\b))?
```

[Regex demo of the full pattern](https://regex101.com/r/QtOXc2/1)

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the detailed explanations, I don't fully understand the issue I had with the groupings so will need to read over that a few more times - FYI not only does your solution work perfectly but its 25x faster than my original.

Comment: This is great work, but the problem is that it identifies abbreviations that don't have a chapter number, so it also finds common words like "so", "is", and "am" in addition to a few other HTML-specific things like "th", "col", etc. I think it should be updated to not just find a book name, but require at the very least a whitespace and a number following it.

You'd get fewer false positives by forcing a verse (indicated by a colon `;`) but then you miss anything from Jude, which doesn't use chapters. I feel like any regex like this needs to handle two separate cases: Jude + all other books.